# How to vectorize a function that reduces an array to a scalar—or shut off the warning message?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, suppress-warnings

I'm making a surface plot of the [LogSumExp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp) function. This function is similar to *max,* in that it takes a set of numbers and returns (approximately) the maximum of those numbers; unlike *max,* the LogSumExp function is smooth. To understand the LogSumExp function, I'd like to see it plotted with inputs consisting of sets of just two numbers, serving as the x and y coordinates of a surface plot.

The following code:

```
function lse = lse(x)
   lse = log(sum(exp(x)));
end

fsurf(@(x,y) lse([x y]))
```

plots the graph (success!) but produces this warning message:

```
Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve
performance, properly vectorize your function to return an output with
the same size and shape as the input arguments. 
> In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionSurface>getFunction
In matlab.graphics.function/FunctionSurface/updateFunction
In matlab.graphics.function/FunctionSurface/set.Function
In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionSurface
In fsurf>singleFsurf (line 267)
In fsurf>@(f)singleFsurf(cax,{f},extraOpts,args) (line 233)
In fsurf>vectorizeFsurf (line 233)
In fsurf (line 206)
```

From Internet searches and other StackOverflow answers, I've learned that `fsurf` tries to pass a vector directly to the function in order to get a vector back, because that yields faster performance than calling the function once for every (*x, y*) pair.

The LogSumExp function, however, by definition reduces a vector to a scalar, so I'm not even sure that it is possible to vectorize it.

Is there a way to vectorize LogSumExp? If not, is there a way to prevent the warning message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function. It can be used in two ways (or variations thereof):

1. `max(x, y)` computes the element-wise maximum of `x` and `y`:

   ```
   >> max([10 20], [0 30]) 
   ans =
       10    30
   ```
2. `max(x, [], n)` computes the maximum of `x` along its dimension `n`:

   ```
   >> max([10 20; 0 30], [], 1)
   ans =
       10    30
   ```

You have defined your `lse` function using the first approach. However, the *second* is more suited to vectorization. To define `lse` using the second approach, note that [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) also works that way, with the syntax `sum(x, n)`:

```
function lse = lse(x, n)
   lse = log(sum(exp(x), n));
end
```

The anonymous function passed to `fsurf` can then be defined as `@(x,y) lse(cat(3, x, y), 3)`, using the fact that the arguments `x`, `y` with which `fsurf` will call it [are](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fsurf.html#bu62pyw-1-f) *matrices* (i.e. `2` dimensions). Thus,

```
fsurf(@(x,y) lse(cat(3, x, y), 3))
```

produces the plot without warnings:

[image]

Comment: Wow. I think I learned more about how to think about Matlab from this answer than from any previous experience. I may never write a loop again. ;) Thanks!